# Retrieving copied text from clipboard

Tags: c#

I'm trying to retrieve text copied to the clipboard, but text never gets retrieved.

I am using this piece of code:

```
if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
{                              
    text = Clipboard.GetText();
}
```

Now this condition never returns true, which means clipboard never contains any text, although I copied several pieces of text to the clipboard.

I also tried this code too and it's the same:

```
   IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

   if (iData != null && iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
   {
         text = (String)iData.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You specify your format in your Contains, here an sample with html data

use `ContainsData` and  `GetText`

```
     bool IsHTMLDataOnClipboard = Clipboard.ContainsData(DataFormats.Html);
     string htmlData;
     if(IsHTMLDataOnClipboard)
     {
         htmlData = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html);
     }
```

Comment: if Clipboard.ContainsText() returns false it means it doesnt contains any text with any format, how ever i tried your code and its the same

Comment: You must just adapt your format Stacker, my code is good for html format

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use;

```
    static string clipHTML { get; set; } 

    public yourclass()
    {

    clipHTML = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html);

    }
```

Depending on what .NET Framework you are using you might head warning below.

**DataFormats.Html** [specification](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html) states it's encoded in UTF-8. But there's a bug in .NET 4 Framework and lower, and it actually reads as UTF-8 as **Windows-1252**.

You get allot of wrong encodings, which leading to funny/bad characters such as 
'Å','â€¹','Å’','Å½','Å¡','Å“','Å¾','Å¸','Â','Â¡','Â¢','Â£','Â¤','Â¥','Â¦','Â§','Â¨','Â©'

For example '€' is wrongly encoded as   'â‚¬' in Windows-1252.

Full explanation here at this dedicated website
[Debugging Chart Mapping Windows-1252 Characters to UTF-8 Bytes to Latin-1 Characters](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html)

But by using the [conversions tables](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html) you will not loose any UTF-8 characters. You can get the original pristine UTF-8 characters from DataFormats.Html. (Note: Ppm solution defaults to ASCII for this & you loose information)

Soln: Create a translation dictionary and search and replace.